# Specializing template with integer_sequence. GCC vs MSVC

Tags: c++, templates

So, I came across a piece of code that behaves differently in GCC and MSVC:

```
#include <utility>

typedef int IType;

template<typename> struct A;

template<int... Ns>
struct A<std::integer_sequence<IType, Ns...>> {
    using type = bool; 
};

using B = typename A<std::make_integer_sequence<IType, 3>>::type;

int main() {
    B b;
}
```

This happily compiles on both compilers. However, if you define IType as `typedef long IType;` MSVC still works whereas GCC says:

```
source>:12:61: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A<std::integer_sequence<long int, 0, 1, 2> >'

   12 | using B = typename A<std::make_integer_sequence<IType, 3>>::type;

      |                                                             ^~~~

<source>:5:27: note: declaration of 'struct A<std::integer_sequence<long int, 0, 1, 2> >'

    5 | template<typename> struct A;

      |                           ^

<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:15:3: error: 'B' was not declared in this scope

   15 |   B b;

      |   ^

Compiler returned: 1
```

So, obviously when IType is long GCC fails to use the 2nd more specialized definition of A and thus fails. I'm really struggling to understand why `int` and `long` are treated differently by GCC here.

I used GCC 10.1 and MSVC 19.24 in Compiler Explorer to play with it.
https://godbolt.org/z/7L3xap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) is defined as

```
template< class T, T... Ints >
class integer_sequence;
```

That is, the type of the values is `T`.

So when changing `IType` to `long`, also the type of `Ns...` should be changed to `long...`:

```
typedef int IType;

template<typename> struct A;

template<IType... Ns>  // <--- HERE
struct A<std::integer_sequence<IType, Ns...>> {
    using type = bool; 
};
```

Otherwise you get a specialization of `struct A<long, int, int, int>` which won't match `struct A<long, long, long, long>` (MSVC seems to be more lenient on this, but GCC behavior is more correct IMO).

Comment: Note that clang also takes the more lenient approach. It would be interesting to dig into, from a language-lawyer perspective, who is actually correct here as per the standard.

Comment: Right. Now, after it has been been answered, it seems like a really silly question. =) Thank you.

Comment: @DmitryBezer I think it's a rather interesting question, particularly as both MSVC and Clang accepts this code. Is this subsequently a bug in MSVC and Clang?

Comment: @dfri you're welcome to re-ask the question with a tag [tag:language-lawyer]. As can be seen, OP is not interested in digging that deep at the moment.

Comment: @ rustyx: Thanks, I tried to dig into the relevant standard parts myself but without avail, so I posted a [similar language-lawyer-tagged question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62636822), with a scaled-down example (not including e.g. template parameter packs).