# Partial specialization of single type template parameter class template using non-type template parameter through a dependent type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int N> struct num {};

template <typename> struct A;

// (1)
template <int N> struct A<num<N>> { using type = bool; };

// (2)
template <long N> struct A<num<N>> { using type = char; };

static_assert(!std::is_same_v<long, int>, "");

// (A)
static_assert(std::is_same_v<A<num<1>>::type, bool>, "");

int main() {}
```

The `static_assert` at **(A)** is successful for GCC, but fails for Clang:

> ```
> error: static_assert failed due to 
>        requirement 'std::is_same_v<char, bool>' ""
> ```

Essentially, GCC picks the perfectly matching specialization **(1)**, whereas Clang picks the specialization **(2)**.

Similarly, if we remove the assertions as well as specialization **(1)**:

```
template <int N> struct num {};

template <typename> struct A;

// (2)
template <long N> struct A<num<N>> { using type = char; };

int main() {
  A<num<1>> a{};
  (void)a;
}
```

Then GCC fails to compile the program whereas Clang accepts it.

> GCC:
>
> ```
> error: variable '`A<num<1> > a`' has initializer but incomplete type
> ```

This behaviour holds over various GCC and Clang versions, as well as various C++ language levels over these version (C++11, C++14, C++17, C++2a).

#### Question

- Is the first snippet above in fact ill-formed (no diagnostic required?), or is either GCC or Clang wrong?

My guess is that this is ill-formed, but haven't been able to apply a relevant part of [[temp.class.spec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec) to reject it. Perhaps [[temp.class.spec]/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec#8.1)?

> **[temp.class.spec]/8.1** The type of a template parameter corresponding to a specialized non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of the specialization. [ *Example: [...] — end example* ]

Comment: I'm fairly certain that a violation of any **[temp.class.spec]/8** bullet is diagnosable. So the specialization itself would have been flagged.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I agree, the examples therein are even categorised as either _OK_ or _Error_.

Comment: Is it similar to http://wg21.link/cwg1647?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer it is indeed similar, and we can apply [a similar example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kkuU6aS2t4g1Qpm8) to the one of CWG Issue 1687 that is accepted by Clang but rejected by GCC; as written in the issue report, _"There is implementation variance in the treatment of this example."_. This would not explain why Clang, with its apparent "this is valid C++ code" interpretation (unless the example above is actually ill-formed, no diagnostic required, for other reasons than standard ambiguity), chooses the promotion to `long` specialization over the perfect match `int` splzation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the first snippet is ill-formed (and a diagnostic *is required*); compilers should reject the program because of the partial specialization (2).

[[temp.deduct.type]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#18) applies here:

> If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of `i` differs
> from the type of the corresponding template parameter of the template
> named by the enclosing *simple-template-id*, deduction fails. [...]

The associated example in the Standard uses a function template, but is otherwise very similar.

So the template argument of the partial specialization (2) can never be deduced, and [[temp.class.spec.match]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec.match#3) applies:

> If the template arguments of a partial specialization cannot be
> deduced because of the structure of its *template-parameter-list* and
> the *template-id*, the program is ill-formed.

---

Interestingly, I couldn't find a compiler that diagnoses this issue, not even EDG in strict mode. We could speculate that most compiler writers consider the benefits of having a diagnostic here not to be worth the effort of implementing the checks. This could mean that we might see the requirement in the paragraph above change in the future from *ill-formed* to *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*. However, this is pure speculation. In any case, I don't see it ever changing to *well-formed*; I can't think of a valid use for a partial specialization that never matches.

---

The wording of [[temp.deduct.type]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#18) was clarified by the resolution of [CWG2091](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2091).

Comment: Thanks, I will read up on [temp.deduct.type] before accepting this (or the other) answer (both answers sounds sound, but give different views w.r.t. well-formed vs ill-formed).

Comment: @dfri Yeah, I didn't notice that Davis' answer also mentions that rule from §18. I saw "partial ordering" at the beginning there and just glanced over the rest, since we're definitely not getting as far as partial ordering in this case. Had I noticed that earlier, lazy as I am, I probably would have just commented on his answer, pointing to [temp.class.spec.match]/3, and would have saved you the trouble of choosing between the two :-).

Answer (score 1):

The standard is not nearly precise enough about the template argument deduction for a partial specialization ([temp.class.spec.match]/2) to definitively determine the meaning of your example.  In particular, all deduction is ultimately defined in terms of **types** ([temp.deduct.type]), but there are no types involved for a non-type template argument.

The deduction for partial ordering among partial specializations handles this case in terms of an invented class template ([temp.class.order]/1.2), which brings to bear the rule that deduction fails for any **mismatch** between the type of a non-type template argument and its parameter ([temp.deduct.type]/18).  That makes any use of `A<num<…>>` in your example ambiguous *if* both partial specializations match (avoiding the need to determine whether a narrowing conversion was involved in using the “unique value” synthesized for partial ordering ([temp.func.order]/3) as a template argument).  However, if we apply the same rule to the matching itself, we find (as does **GCC**) that (2) never matches.  In turn, that arguably should provoke a diagnostic for the specialization itself ([temp.class.spec.match]/3, as bogdan’s answer mentioned), although it’s not entirely obvious what “structure” there is meant to include if the error is to be diagnosable and no compiler rejects it.

Meanwhile, [temp.class.spec]/8.1 is certainly irrelevant: there are no specialized non-type arguments involved.